# Unexpected inheritance behavior using get_class_vars() in __contruct()

Tags: php, oop

I'm running into an inheritance issue. Below is the code:

```
namespace{
    $resume=new resume('\\resume');
    class resume{
        function __construct($className){
            $children=get_class_vars($className);
            foreach($children as$name=>$var){
                $fqcn=$className."\\$name";
                $this->{$name}=new $fqcn($fqcn);
            }
        }
        private$evan;
        private$education;
        private$employment;
        private$expertise;
        private$portfolio;
    }
}
namespace resume{
    class evan extends \resume{
        private$information;
        private$permAddress;
        private$businessAddress;
    }
}
```

When I dump the results of `get_class_vars()` I get the following:

```
array(5) {
   ["evan"]=>
  NULL
  ["education"]=>
  NULL
  ["employment"]=>
  NULL
  ["expertise"]=>
  NULL
  ["portfolio"]=>
  NULL
}
array(5) {
  ["evan"]=>
  NULL
  ["education"]=>
  NULL
  ["employment"]=>
  NULL
  ["expertise"]=>
  NULL
  ["portfolio"]=>
  NULL
}
```

My expected result is:

```
array(5) {
   ["evan"]=>
  NULL
  ["education"]=>
  NULL
  ["employment"]=>
  NULL
  ["expertise"]=>
  NULL
  ["portfolio"]=>
  NULL
}
array(5) {
  ["information"]=>
  NULL
  ["permAddress"]=>
  NULL
  ["businessAddress"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Dumping `$className` gives me:

```
\resume
\resume\evan
```

Then it breaks upon trying to access `\resume\evan\evan`. So apparently the argument passed into `get_class_vars()` is correct, but the output remains static across children...

Comment: You'd probably have to do some reflection to get this right, whatever it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: See georgs answer. This works, it's just a visibility issue. I don't care about visibility in this case, so I'll just make the child properties public.

Comment: It may work, but from the looks of things it's horribly backward and really shouldn't be called OOP ;-)

Comment: Haha don't need it to be pretty, just need it to craft me a resume :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter test case:

```
class A {
    private $aa;

    function fun($cls) {
        print_r(get_class_vars($cls));
    }
}

class B extends A{
    private $bb;
}

$a = new A;
$a->fun('A');
$a->fun('B');
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [aa] => 
)
Array
(
    [aa] => 
)
```

The problem is that when you call `get_class_vars` from `A`, it has no access to privates of `B` and therefore displays only its own privates. If you replace `private` with `protected`, it will show both `aa` and `bb`. I'm not aware of a way to get only own properties of a class, but this is pretty easy to implement along the lines of `array_diff(derived-class-props, base-class-props)`.

Comment: Just found this out myself. I'll accept this in a minute.